# How can I truncate a string to a maximum length without breaking ANSI escape codes

Tags: javascript, node.js, ansi-escape

I have a child process in Node.js which is producing ANSI-escape coloured output which is sometimes wider than my terminal.

I want to truncate the long lines, but without breaking the ANSI colour codes, and without counting the invisible characters (so that lines with lots of escapes aren't *too* short)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need to ensure you handle complete lines from `stdout`, which may give fragments between lines:

```
var acc = '';
child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');       // get strings rather than buffers
child.stdout.on('data', function(data){ // when output is written by child

    // split lines, including linebreaks:
    data.split(/(\r?\n)/).forEach(function(frag) {
        if (frag == '\r\n' || frag == '\n') {        // if linebreak,
            console.log(filterAnsi(acc, width));     //   output filtered completed line
            acc = '';                                //   clear accumulator line
        } else {                                     // if not linebreak,
            acc += frag;                             //   add fragment to accumulator
        }
    });
});
```

Next the filter itself:

```
// Crop the length of lines, ANSI escape code aware
// Always outputs every escape char, regardless of length (so we always end up with a sane state)
// Visible characters are filtered out once length is exceeded
function filterAnsi(str, len) {
    if (!len || len < 10) return str; // probably not a valid console -- send back the whole line
    var count = 0,        // number of visible chars on line so far
        esc = false,      // in an escape sequence
        longesc = false;  // in a multi-character escape sequence
    var outp = true;      // should output this character
    return str.split('').filter(function(c){ // filter characters...
        if (esc && !longesc && c == '[') longesc = true; // have seen an escape, now '[', start multi-char escape
        if (c == '\x1b') esc = true; // start of escape sequence

        outp = (count < len || esc); // if length exceeded, don't output non-escape chars
        if (!esc && !longesc) count++; // if not in escape, count visible char

        if (esc && !longesc && c != '\x1b') esc = false; // out of single char escape
        if (longesc && c != '[' && c >= '@' && c <= '~') {esc=false; longesc=false;} // end of multi-char escape

        return outp; // result for filter
    }).join(''); // glue chars back into string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this tiny NPM library: [printable-characters](https://github.com/xpl/printable-characters) (note: *I'm the author of this library*)

It handles all kinds of burden with processing strings containing zero-width characters and ANSI escape codes.

Getting first N symbols without breaking ANSI codes:

```
const { first } = require ('printable-characters')

const s = '\u001b[22mfoobar\u001b[22m'

first (s, 0) // === '\u001b[22m\u001b[22m'
first (s, 1) // === '\u001b[22mf\u001b[22m'
first (s, 3) // === '\u001b[22mfoo\u001b[22m'
first (s, 6) // === '\u001b[22mfoobar\u001b[22m'
```